# Display all posts/pages in a multiple selectbox

Tags: posts, pages

So I'm looking for a way to show all posts/pages inside a multiple selectbox, which is used to select and store which page/posts has been checked in order to display some text on that page(custom plugin).

I'm looking to get the id of the posts/pages so that I can save these and use on the frontend of the templates. I did use get_pages() but these dont output anykind of page id.

Comment: use a `foreach`!???? are you designing a custom plugin or for use with a custom plugin?

Comment: the foreah part I do understand and yes it's my own plugin.

Comment: You need to post way more information about this question if you expect to get an answer. And take a look at WP_QUERY

Comment: I would edit your question as at the moment we're not sure where you're having problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_pages` returns an array of post objects, so you would use `foreach` to iterate over each object and grab the ID and whatever else you want to use:

```
<?php
  if ( $pages = get_pages( $args ) {
    echo "<select multiple>";
    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
      echo "<option value='{$page->ID}'>{$page->post_title}</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
  }
?>
```